# Vue.js why can't I create unique key for v-for by calling a method?

Tags: vue.js

I came across a case where I need to iterate from n to 10 using a v-for, and I wanted to use the uuid v4 method to generate a unique key for each loop. I've tried different ways to make the call but it just doesn't seem to be possible and I would like to understand why.
I also tried to log the function but nothing showed up.

```
[Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: 'function() {
    [native code]
}'. This may cause an update error.
```

```
<span v-for="index in getTableLength" :key="getUuid">{{n}}</span>
```

```
import {v4 as uuidV4} from 'uuid'
```

```
 methods: {
    getUuid(){
        return uuidV4()
     },
```

Thank's for the help

Answer (score 2):

`:key` does not evaluate the function like a method call.
Because it is a key part in optimizing the update mechanism, it turns any value it gets into a string (if not already a string) and then uses that for comparison. So here you see the result of what happens when you call `toString()` on a function.

Use it like so instead:

```
<span v-for="index in getTableLength" :key="getUuid()" />
```

But this will basically be the same as not setting a `v-bind:key` in the first place, because every invoke will produce a new result.
This means that the node will never be matched and always recreated, no reuse between render updates. So it actually may be worse because that is the same as having no key, but now you also call a function as well.

I personally tend to create arrays with preformatted data in a computed getter instead.

Comment: It's not quite the same as having no key at all - when there is no key, Vue may skip re-rendering or (most probably) will update/patch wrong DOM nodes. I've experienced the latter.

Comment: Ah, thanks for letting me know. I've hardly ever used v-for as number range generator so I'm not too familiar with that case

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling your UUID function - you're merely passing a reference to it. Add braces `()` to actually call the function.

Comment: Ah yep i didn't even thought about it, i even tried () => getUuid() before. 
I'm used to call my computed method like that in the html, that's why, example: v-if="!isRoot" thank's